# SQLAlchemy has_any()

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

I cannot get the SQLAlchemy's `has_any()` function to work. I simply want to filter my result on a list contained in a jsonb column:

```
db.session.query(models.Record.id).\
    filter(models.Record.record_metadata["teams"].has_any(team_ids))
```

`models.Record.record_metadata["teams"]` being a list of ids in a jsonb column (`record_metadata`) that i want to compare with `team_ids` that is also a list of ids

The query generated is :

```
SELECT record.id AS record_id
FROM record
WHERE ((record.record_metadata -> 'teams')) ?| '["id1", "id2"]';
```

That gives the error

```
DataError: (psycopg2.DataError) malformed array literal: "["id1", "id2"]"
LINE 3: WHERE ((record.record_metadata -> 'teams')) ?| '["id1", "id2"]'
                                                       ^
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
```

But regarding [Table 9.44. Additional jsonb Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-json.html) on Postgres official documentation, the `|?` operator should be followed by an `array[]`

Indeed, when i manually write the query :

```
SELECT record.id AS record_id
FROM record
WHERE ((record.record_metadata -> 'teams')) ?| array['id1', 'id2'];
```

It works just fine.

[SQLAlchemy's documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB.Comparator.has_any) about this function is pretty poor and I can't find any examples.

So is it me doing something wrong with this function? Should I use something else for this case? Or is it `has_any()` that is broken?

**EDIT :**

```
SELECT record.id AS record_id
FROM record
WHERE ((record.record_metadata -> 'teams')) ?| '{"id1", "id2"}';
```

Works fine as well, and I found out that `has_any()` accepts strings as well.

So it s a (very) nasty fix, but if I format a string with the desired ids :

```
db.session.query(models.Record.id).\
    filter(models.Record.record_metadata["teams"].has_any(
        str(team_ids).
        replace('[', '{').
        replace(']', '}').
        replace('\'', '\"')))
```

It works...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'd seem that by default the passed value is JSON encoded, if it is a `list` or a `dict`. You can work around that by passing an explicit [`array` literal](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.array):

```
In [15]: from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import array

In [16]: session.query(Foo).\
    ...:     filter(Foo.data['test'].has_any(array(['1', '2']))).all()
2018-06-18 09:07:20,780 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2018-06-18 09:07:20,780 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT foo.id AS foo_id, foo.data AS foo_data 
FROM foo 
WHERE ((foo.data -> %(data_1)s)) ?| ARRAY[%(param_1)s, %(param_2)s]
2018-06-18 09:07:20,781 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'data_1': 'test', 'param_1': '1', 'param_2': '2'}
Out[16]: []
```

This way you do not need to manually format the array literal from the string representation of a Python `list`, which is probably rather error prone.

The error itself is the result of Postgresql trying to parse the passed literal – containing JSON – as an array. As the error states, the [text representation of an array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO) may start with a dimension decoration that specifies the array's subscript ranges:

> ```
> '[1:1][-2:-1][3:5]={{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}}'::int[]
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! SQLAlchemy's documentation is pretty obscure on what can be passed to this function.

Comment: Wouldnt that make sense that `has_any()` accepts python lists and encode them as a proper array rather than encode the object parameter as JSON?

Comment: I'd agree. At least it'd be nice that the documentation at least mentions this potential pitfall. I wonder if there's an issue about this already in the tracker.